# Calling external commands when switching branches

Tags: git, bash

I want to restart my virtual server after switching branches, and tried adding some aliases in my `.gitconfig` but did not get it to work.

```
co = checkout | !rap
```

only runs rap, the restart script.

```
co = checkout && !rap
```

and some other things I tried (like `checkout $1`) gives my "git usage: bla bla".

Comment: Of course I meant to do a checkout. I'll blame the lack of coffee as everyone else.

Comment: You can edit your question to correct it, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, what you really want is `post-checkout` hook (look into your `.git/hooks/` directory and [githooks manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)).

Comment: Thanks but.. I tried
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "foo"
in .git/hooks/post-checkout and `chmod +x post-checkout`, but git-checkout doesn't echo anything!

Comment: I have just checked and it does echo. What happens if you run `./.git/hooks/post-checkout` directly?

Comment: It echoes fine when running it directly. I even tried `git-init` but it didn't matter.

Comment: Or.. what is your `git` version?

Comment: I've checked the git repository, looks like the first release, that incorporates `post-checkout` hook is `1.5.4-rc0`. Can you upgrade your git or is it not an option?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I checked the docs on our machine and they included post-checkout so I thought it was there. I will see if I can get the admins to upgrade.

Comment: This is weird. The post-checkout docs have been included in the same commit as functionality. Maybe you have docs from different version...

Answer (score 6):

**Note** that the correct solution to your ***problem*** could be simply using `post-checkout` [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), as written in [hacker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491556/calling-external-commands-with-git-aliases/1491605#1491605).

Below there is posible solution for your ***question***.

---

You either use single git command in alias, like e.g.

```
[alias]
    alias = config --get-regexp ^alias\\.
```

or you use any command with '!' prefix, perhaps using "`sh -c`" trick; then you have to spell "git command", e.g.

```
[alias]
    sed = !git ls-files --stage | grep ^100 | awk '{print $4}' | xargs sed
    who = "!sh -c 'git log -1 --pretty=\"format:%an <%ae>\" --author=\"$1\"' -"
```

(not that `alias.sed` is the best solution).

---

If you want for "`git br <somebranch>`" to do "`git checkout <somebranch>`", then "`rap`", try

```
[alias]
    br = !sh -c 'git checkout "$0" && rap'
```

Here `&&` means: do next command if previous one is succesfull. You can use `;` instead to run command regardless of status of earlier command

BTW don't you *switch* branches using "`git checkout <branch>`"? The "`git branch <branchname>`" *creates* branch, without checking it out.

Comment: It wasn't really a solution to my question, but very generic. I tried `co = "!sh -c 'git checkout \"$1\"' | rap -"` and `co = !git checkout $1 | rap -` and it still only runs rap.

Comment: Errr... "`|`" means to pipe output of command (connest standard output of earlier with standard input of later command). You need to use "`&&`", or "`;`".  See also updated answer.

Comment: +1 for answering the *question*.  The main failure of the stackexchange sites is that quite often the accepted answer has nothing to do with the question asked, but instead the answer addresses the need behind the question - useful for the questioner, worthless to people searching later on.